# Flex column causes auto-fit grid to have single column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid that works fine until I wrap it in a flex column. Below is the most minimal example I could narrow it down to. The example shows the hello divs are displayed in a single column, when I was expecting multiple columns. I've found I can fix this and make the grid layout as expected by either adding `.grid { width: 100% }` or removing the `.wrapper { align-items: flex-start; }` however I do not understand why either fixes the problem. This issue caused me hours of debugging and I would really like to understand the underlying rules governing this behavior so I can avoid similar mistakes in the future.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* width: 100%; */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241697/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the flex container (`.wrapper`) to `align-items: flex-start`,  it packs the flex item (`.grid`), to the start of the container. See the image below, with added borders for illustration.

```
.wrapper = flex container = black border
.grid = flex item = red border
```

[image]

Notice that the flex column has a minimum width of 100px, per the grid code.

When you remove `align-items: flex-start`, the container falls back to its default setting: `align-items: stretch`, which provides `.grid` with full use of the horizontal space in the container.

[image]

When you set `.grid` to `width: 100%`, it overrides `align-items` and, like with `stretch`, provides `.grid` with full use of the horizontal space.